# return value from javascript should be assigned to an array in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, arrays, json

I have a javascript function that returns an array.

I would like to know

- (a) how to call the Javascript function in OnInit or Onload
- (b) The javascript function returns an array and I want it to be stored within an array in my c# code.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Update1: Javascript function is something like below.

```
function RenderUrl() 
{
    var url = "http://myurl.com/mypage?Id=420&Width=30"; //this is a dummy url.

    var qsBegin = url.indexOf("?");
    var qsPattern = new RegExp("[?&]([^=]*)=([^&]*)", "ig");
    var match = qsPattern.exec(url);
    var params = new Array();

    while (match != null) 
        {
            var matchID = match[1];
                if ( matchID.charAt(0) == "&" ) 
            {
                    matchID = matchID.substr(1);
                }

                if ( params[match[1]] != null && !(params[match[1]] instanceof Array) ) 
            {
                    var subArray = new Array();
                    subArray.push(params[match[1]]);
                    subArray.push(unescape(match[2]));
                    params[match[1]] = subArray;
                }
            else if ( params[match[1]] != null && params[match[1]] instanceof Array ) 
            {
                    params[match[1]].push(unescape(match[2]));
            }
            else 
            {
                params[match[1]]=unescape(match[2]);
                }
            match = qsPattern.exec(url);
        }
    return params;
}
```

**Update 2: My c# code so far (not working as expected but I am checking currently)**

```
 private void ParseUrl(string Url)
{
    int WhereToBegin = Url.IndexOf("?");
    string pattern = @"[?&]([^=]*)=([^&]*)";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(Url);
    while (matches != null)
    {
        string matchID = matches[0].ToString();
        if (matchID.Substring(0, 1) == "&")
        {
            matchID = matchID.Substring(1);
        }

    //Push to the new array named PARAMS here (under construction)
      ..
      ..    
    //End array construction.

        matches = rgx.Matches(Url);
    }
    //Finally return the array once it is working fine.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying makes sense. You have some javascript code (which runs on the CLIENT computer), which you want to run when the page loads on the CLIENT computer, and somehow return that array of data to the SERVER? Perhaps you should explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you add a bit more info? What is the javascript function? And what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: you can get data from the javascript on post back... is this good for you ?

Comment: @ean5533: I have updated my post with the javascript function I have.

Comment: @Tallmaris: I have updated my post with javascript function I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript that you posted just extracts the parameters from the URL of the page. You don't need to use javascript to get that information in ASP.NET, you can get it from C# directly by looking at `Request.QueryString` (among other ways)

Comment: apart from extracting parameters, it has few more logic. I tried to rewrite using c# but didn't work. If it is possible, please provide any examples closer to the above code.

Comment: What else does your code do that you weren't able to replicate in C#?

Comment: What I want to achieve in c# code : Parse the URL but we do not know how many parameters it will contain. Also for each parameter that we find, it has to be reconstructed similar to the Jscript logic. Finally I will need to rebuild the URL again with the array that contains list of all parameters. Note this URL is not the page URL but the URL of an control that needs to be shown in that page. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: All of that can be done is C# just as easily as javascript. C# has regular expressions and arrays and string manipulation. I suggest you start by looking at `Regex.Match`.

Comment: My c# code (so far) is pasted in Update2. I am working on it right now but kind of stuck with array creation. If you can provide any inputs, it will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, you cannot call client side code from server side code.